# need fast date converter for pytables

Tags: python, numpy, pytables

I have to convert a lot of csv data to a pytable.  I can do the job in 5 hours, if I just store the dates as strings.  But, that's not useful for query operation, so I would like it as an integer, or some format that makes searches quicker.

Here's what I have tried:

1. ```
   np.datetime64(date)
   ```

   This is fast, but pytables will not store it directly, as I write with numpy structured arrays and type 'M8' is not accepted. 
   Converting to int64 using astype slows the process considerably.
2. ```
   ts = time.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
   calendar.timegm(ts)
   ```

   Too slow.  Causes total processing time to go to 15 hours

I just want some kind of number to represent a day number since 2000.  I don't need hours, seconds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you could improve on that by using the slow method, but caching the results in a dictionary after computation.  So 1) check a (possibly global) dictionary to see if that string exists as a key; if so, use the value for that key. 2) if not, then compute the date for the string. 3) add the string/date as a key/value in the dictionary for next time. Assuming you have a lot of duplicates, which you must (because it sounds like you have a gigantic pile of data, and there aren't that many distinct days between 2000 and now) then you will get a fantastic cache hit rate. Fetching from a dictionary is an O(1) operation; that should improve things a lot.

Comment: Good idea.  Thanks.  It's true, there are lots of duplicate dates. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

This is kind of late, but I've written fast Cython-based converter precisely for this kind of task:

https://bitbucket.org/mrkafk/fastdateconverter

Essentially, you give it a date format and it generates Cython code that is then compiled to Python extension. This makes it so fast, see example in `date_converter_generator.py`:

```
fdef1 = FunDef('convert_date_fast', '2014/01/07 10:15:08', year_offset=0,
               month_offset=5, day_offset=8, hour_offset=11, minute_offset=14, second_offset=17)
cg = ConverterGenerator([fdef1])
cg.benchmark()
```